# Error importing XML file with accent mark in Android Eclipse

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, import, resources

I have many .xml files for import to the "value" folder in the Android project (Eclipse), and these files contain String resources with this (´) accent mark (spanish accent). When I import these files, the characters with accent mark change to this character (�), but the original files are fine.

Comment: looks like a charset problem. What ide are you using?

Comment: But I'm using utf-8 encoding in the xml files. I think that is an Eclipse preference, but I don't know

Comment: yep I do think it is just an issue with eclipse

Comment: What *font* is it set to use? Does it support that character?

Comment: Is just a xml file written in notepad

Comment: if they were just a few files, there would be no problem, but these are many

Answer (score 2):

You should migrate to Android Studio. If you prefer to keep using Eclipse, make sure you save your String resources with UTF-8 encoding. This is common when trying to importing projects from another computer. Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

Might it be of any help.
I could solve all my accent issue when using Eclipse, ensuring that Eclipse preferences (Windows->preferences->General->Content Types... and sub-entries were all setup : Default encoding UTF-8.